# Prevent resetting a textarea

Tags: javascript, php, textarea, submit, reset

when I press the "Send" button, PHP checks if the field "pm_to" is <1.
If successful, open an alert, but when I press OK on the alert, all the text that I had written in the textarea "area1" is deleted. How do I prevent this?
Here's the code.

```
<? 
$txtmsg=addslashes($_POST[area1]);
if($_POST[sendpm]=="Invia il messaggio"){
    if(strlen($pm_to)<1){
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Non puoi lasciare il campo destinatario vuoto, riprova.");
        </script>
    <?
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
A: <input class="pm_" type="text" name="pm_to" size="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;Oggetto: <input size="30" class="pm_" type="text" name="pm_subj" >
<br /><br />
<textarea style="height: 200px; width: 800px; text-align: left;" id="area1" name="area1"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="sendpm">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP, but my guess is that you need to repopulate the html when you send it back to the client from the server. Something like this?

```
<textarea style="height: 200px; width: 800px; text-align: left;" id="area1" name="area1"> 
<? print($_POST[area1])>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements do not maintain their values when a form request is made. You need to do it manually:

```
<textarea style="height: 200px; width: 800px; text-align: left;" id="area1" name="area1">
<?= isset($_POST['area1']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['area1']) : ''; ?>
</textarea>
```

In this case I am using an inline if to check if the variable `$_POST['area1']` is set. If yes, it prints your value HTML-escaped, otherwise it'll print an empty string (nothing).

You should do the same with the other inputs. For example:

```
<input class="pm_" type="text" name="pm_to" size="15" value="<?= isset($_POST['pm_to']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['pm_to']) : ''; ?>">
```